# get hold of a list

Tags: list, splist

$web gives me the title of the website 
$list is not giving me any and therefore item add/update i m doing is failing. What is wrong? The code works in dev area. btw, I am running with full rights on the app server.

```
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq “Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell”}) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

$web = Get-SPWeb "http://intranet.Rubbermaid.com/Sales" 
$ListName = "2012SalesReport1Q"
$list = $web.Lists[$ListName]

write-host $web
write-host $list
write-host " - - - - Starting Process - - - - "
```

Rest of the code...

Comment: basically $web.Lists[$ListName] not working. I even tried $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName) and still the same. But they work fine in dev area.

Comment: I tried almost all the list on that site collection and none seem to answer my call. so what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means `$web.Lists[$ListName]` returns null. The reason is that you should pass title, not list root folder name or list url, to the [SPWeb.Lists[string]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms443550.aspx) indexer. For example:

```
$list = $web.Lists["My precious list"]
```

I assume **2012SalesReport1Q** in your code refers to the list root folder name, i.e. it has address `http://portal/Lists/2012SalesReport1Q`. In this case, to get the list object, you should use [SPWeb.GetListFromWebPartPageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlistfromwebpartpageurl.aspx) method (a bit long, yep :)..):

```
$list = $web.GetListFromWebPartPageUrl("http://portal/Lists/2012SalesReport1Q/AllItems.aspx")
```

Notice we have to pass full url of the list view page, including "AllItems.aspx", otherwise it won't work.

Comment: The list name is "2012SalesReport1Q" and there are no folders under this list. so what to do?

Comment: Go to the list view page, copy the actual url of the page, and use GetListFromWebPartPageUrl, as I've described above.

Comment: Found the issue. You CAN NOT USE INTERNAL NAME for the list (if internal name is different than external Name) in this code 

so it should be 

$ListName = "External Name"
$List = $web.Lists[$ListName]

This works now. Thanks Andrey

Comment: That is what I meant. What you call "External name" refers to **SPList.Title** property, and what you call "Internal name", is actually the list root folder name: **SPList.RootFolder.Name**.